# Swift 4: Image inside UIView only display after second UIViewController call

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimageview, cell

I inserted a UIView with a image inside a Cell View like tha image bellow.

[image]

What i tried:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.hideProfileDescriptionView.addSubview(self.hidedescriptionLogo)
        self.hideProfileDescriptionView.bringSubview(toFront: 
        self.hidedescriptionLogo)
        self.cellDescriptionView.addSubview(self.hideProfileDescriptionView)
}
```

In the First time I call the UIVIewController, the image does not display, but in the second time I call UIViewController the image appears. 
How can I solve that.

Thanks

Comment: Show up the code you call the UIViewController please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that all cell content was not being displayed, so i discovered a flag that i did put on the code and i did disable that. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case Image didnt load fully and second time download is completed. If you dont to wait this installations You can use **KingFisher** repo https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher .

This repo is highly recommended. Also with this repo you can put **laoder in UIImageView.**

Comment: thanks for answering, but the image is not downloaded from web, the image came from assets.